# I want to print only images with checked checkbox by printer

Tags: jquery, checkbox, printing

there. I want to print only images with checked checkbox by printer.
if someone check checkbox of img id = 9 and 8, and then click the button that class is print. print out the img id = 9 and 8 by printer.
could you help me?

```
<div class="container" id="main"><center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg print" id="print2">복사하기</button></center>

    <div class="profile__body">
      <ul class="row first" data-bsp-ul-id="bsp-PkKH" data-bsp-ul-index="0">

          <li class="col-xs-4 post bspHasModal" data-bsp-li-index="0"><input type="checkbox">
              <div class="picture-square"><img id="9" src="/uploads/static_files/uploaded/2017/%EC%BA%A1%EC%B2%98.JPG" class="img-r img-responsive"></div>
          </li>

          <li class="col-xs-4 post bspHasModal" data-bsp-li-index="1"><input type="checkbox">
              <div class="picture-square"><img id="8" src="/uploads/static_files/uploaded/2017/%EC%BA%A1%EC%B2%98.jpg" class="img-r img-responsive"></div>
          </li>

          <li class="col-xs-4 post bspHasModal" data-bsp-li-index="2"><input type="checkbox">
              <div class="picture-square"><img id="7" src="/uploads/static_files/uploaded/2017/ddd.JPG" class="img-r img-responsive"></div>
          </li><li class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></li>

          <li class="col-xs-4 post bspHasModal" data-bsp-li-index="3"><input type="checkbox">
              <div class="picture-square"><img id="6" src="/uploads/static_files/uploaded/2017/%E1%84%89%E1%85%B3%E1%84%8F%E1%85%B3%E1%84%85%E1%85%B5%E1%86%AB%E1%84%89%E1%85%A3%E1%86%BA_2017-02-05_%E1%84%8B%E1%85%A9%E1%84%92%E1%85%AE_7.42.33.jpg" class="img-r img-responsive"></div>
          </li>

          <li class="col-xs-4 post bspHasModal" data-bsp-li-index="4"><input type="checkbox">
              <div class="picture-square"><img id="4" src="/uploads/static_files/uploaded/2017/2.JPG" class="img-r img-responsive"></div>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

            </div>
```

this is my js.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#print").on('click', function(ev){
            $('#main').prepend('<center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg print" id="print2">복사하기</button></center>')
            $('.post').prepend('<input type="checkbox" />');
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
        $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('img').addClass("img-print");
            } else {
                $('img').removeClass("img-print");
            }
        })
        $("#print2").on('click', function(){

        })
    });
```

Comment: add class of print to relevant image when you check your check box. and assign CSS to that class on print view.

Comment: could you please share your printing related JS code?

Comment: @vijayP i add js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. select all images what checked.
2. create html (`<img src='1.jpg'/> </br> <img src='5.jpg'/>`).

   3.pass html value to **mywindow.document.write(images );**
   http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCP6E6YV4S4T

   ```
   <button> print </button>
   ```

   ```
      $('button').on('click',PrintElem)

   function PrintElem()
       {
            var images = ''
           $.each(selecedImages,(i,d)=>{
          images += '<img src = "+d+" /> '
          });


           mywindow.document.write(images );


           mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
           mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

           mywindow.print();
           mywindow.close();

           return true;

           }
   </script>
   ```